# An `enumerate serial port' loop stops prematurely in Tkinter - but not in IDLE shell

Tags: tkinter, serial-port, port, enumerate

When I run this in an IDLE shell - it works fine
(COM10 is a Virtual COM Port (VCP) USB stick).

```
>>>  from serial import *
>>>  import serial.tools.list_ports
>>>  PortVal = sorted(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
>>>  for n,(p1,p2,p3) in enumerate(PortVal):
>>>         print p1


COM1
COM10
```

HOWEVER, when it runs as a `Button-press-call' function in Tkinter...

```
def ShowPorts():
    PortVal = sorted(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    for n,(p1,p2,p3) in enumerate(PortVal):
        print p1
```

The loop stops after the first iteration, like...

```
(Pressed the RUN button in Wing IDE)
2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Python Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more  information.
[evaluate SerPortTest.py]
```

( I press the `Do-It' button... )

```
COM1
```

And then when I press the button again...

```
COM10
COM1
```

Any ideas as to why-what to do? 
Does this have something to do with a `Try' somewhere?

Comment: I don't think there's enough code to know what the problem is. Are you certain the function is stopping, or could it be that the output just isn't displaying immediately? Perhaps it is the "Wing IDE" that is causing the problem. Have you tried running your code from a command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I no longer care if the Wing IDE screwed me up - which I now believe it did - because I seem to have solved my original "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'" listbox problem. It seemed to work after `.pack'-ing it on a separate line - don't know why. Plus, I have a habit of printing things to the debug window before assigning them to widgets I haven't used before - and then the Wing-101 IDE issue took over.

Working code...

```
from Tkinter import *
from serial import *
import serial.tools.list_ports

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Port List")

# ----------------------------------------------------------
# Widget-called functions
# ----------------------------------------------------------
def ListPorts():
   PortVal = sorted(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
   PortVal = enumerate(PortVal)
   #print list(PortVal)
   for n,(p1,p2,p3) in PortVal:
      PortList.insert( END,p1)

# ----------------------------------------------------------
# GUI Widgets
# ----------------------------------------------------------
FrmPort= Frame(root, padx=10, pady=10, borderwidth=7, relief="raised")

BtnLstPort=Button(FrmPort,text='List COM Ports',command=ListPorts)
PortList=Listbox(FrmPort,height=4,width=8)
BtnLstPort.pack()
PortList.pack()

FrmPort.pack()

# ----------------------------------------------------------
# Let'er rip
# ----------------------------------------------------------
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for your help - little nudges in any direction often spur me on to success. ( Just get me out of my rut!) :-)

PS.  If you are looking for serial ports because you just plugged one in - odds are it's going to be last on the list.
To Auto-default select...

```
PortList.selection_set(END)
PortList.see(END) 
PortList.activate(END)
```

Comment: re: "_It seemed to work after `.pack`-ing it on a separate line - don't know why._". The why has been asked and answered many times on this site. `pack()` returns None, so if you do `foo=Label(...).pack(...)`, foo will always be None. However, this is a completely different problem than what was asked in the question.